# How to verify the certificate used to sign an application on MacOS?

Tags: macos, codesign

I want to get the certificate SHA-1 fingerprint (thumbprint) for the codesigning certificate used to sign a particular file on MacOS. For productsign, I can use

```
shenv@BOSRQWJ2PW5VF Downloads % pkgutil --check-signature test.pkg 
Package "test.pkg":
   Status: signed by a developer certificate issued by Apple for distribution
   Notarization: trusted by the Apple notary service
   Signed with a trusted timestamp on: 2023-04-06 15:20:41 +0000
   Certificate Chain:
    1. Developer ID Installer: Some Company (Some Identifier)
       Expires: 2025-01-06 23:42:22 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           B9 58 25 95 D7 4B 58 A7 C4 F9 58 3D 3E 8B 82 9A 1A A4 ED 88 1C BB 
           67 A8 CE EF 6A F8 B4 C6 D2 81
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2. Developer ID Certification Authority
       Expires: 2027-02-01 22:12:15 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           7A FC 9D 01 A6 2F 03 A2 DE 96 37 93 6D 4A FE 68 09 0D 2D E1 8D 03 
           F2 9C 88 CF B0 B1 BA 63 58 7F
       ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3. Apple Root CA
       Expires: 2035-02-09 21:40:36 +0000
       SHA256 Fingerprint:
           B0 B1 73 0E CB C7 FF 45 05 14 2C 49 F1 29 5E 6E DA 6B CA ED 7E 2C 
           68 C5 BE 91 B5 A1 10 01 F0 24
```

For codesign, I was told that this command returns the fingerprint:

```
% codesign --verbose=4 -dv ~/Downloads/test.pkg                                                                                   
Executable=test.pkg
Identifier=test
Format=generic
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=164 flags=0x0(none) hashes=1+2 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=bd26fd2d0111be2464bad4500330252cd4779623
CandidateCDHashFull sha1=bd26fd2d0111be2464bad4500330252cd4779623
CandidateCDHash sha256=d8c06ce5c57a2c01a97e046c9f1eadab5c9ea39b
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=d8c06ce5c57a2c01a97e046c9f1eadab5c9ea39b194264a67429e36021b48704
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CMSDigest=953f1c7c344798e58fca871b2a5245a460010f9cbaea6fae44f2d626ddcdd1d6
CMSDigestType=2
Page size=none
    -2=69289422c1b6cc9c1bd065cb9e83cd11bae97855c6975c271e9cdfc20ead46af
Launch Constraints:
        None
CDHash=d8c06ce5c57a2c01a97e046c9f1eadab5c9ea39b
Signature size=9048
Authority=Developer ID Application: Some Company (Some Identifier)
Authority=Developer ID Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Timestamp=Jul 19, 2023 at 12:31:34 PM
Info.plist=not bound
TeamIdentifier=Some Identifier
Sealed Resources=none
Internal requirements count=1 size=164
```

What is the SHA-1 fingerprint? Is it **CandidateCDHash sha1=bd26fd2d0111be2464bad4500330252cd4779623**?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed.

Comment: I compared the CandidateCDHash sha1 value with the SHA-1 fingerprint that we computed from the real certificate, and they do not match.

Comment: Ok. How did you compute that?

Comment: I used two methods:
1. This Java code:

                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                byte[] sha1 = md.digest(cert.getEncoded());
                String thumbprint = toHex(sha1).toLowerCase();
2. Imported the certificate into Windows certmgr. The two thumbprints - one computed from the Java code and the other computed by Windows match. But they don't match with the codesign command output.

Comment: Yeah but the certificate itself is not used to sign the code.  That would be fairly short-lived and unmaintainable.  There is a time stamp authority that computes PKI with your certificate and a secure time message for you over the internet, and that is the token used to sign. Because it locks the code to a time when the certificate was valid, the signature lasts for eternity. The certificate is relatively ephemeral, and that is for security reasons.

Comment: It makes sense to timestamp the file, but I still don't understand why codesign would not report the certificate I used to sign. From signature verification perspective, I care much more about verifying the certificate I used at the time of signing. Later if I want to generate a report for my company for auditing purposes(checking what files are signed properly using a key secured in HSM), that will be what gets reported. Or say if I want to revoke a certificate, I need to find out what got signed with it.

Comment: You absolutely can verify the sig but you must go thru the trusted time stamp authority via their public key.  The timestamp authority is higher in the chain of trust than your certificate because it is trusted by the certifying authority (the author of your certificate).  You don’t have the privately-held keys to decrypt anything about the trust relationship which exists between Apple and their time stamp authority provider.

Comment: Plus if you revoke a cert there is nothing preventing the keys being reassigned to a differently-named entity.  Your signing key gets identified by that name and serial number, but cryptographically the keys are consumed by the time stamping authority and remain insulated from the signed code.  Your verification application is required to thumb through all your available keys so identified until a verification is found. If not found then there is no verification.